# Outer glow on 3 sides of a rectangular shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a rectangular shape to which I want to apply an outer glow using Photoshop. I did it but the glow is applied on the four sides, yet my need is to skip the upper side and apply to the remaining ones. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use Layer Masks**

Step 1 : Group the layer which have out glow and make `Layer Mask` as below image

[image]

Step 2 : Select upper area with `Selection Tool` and brush over the selection with black colour that should be hide area as below

[image]

Step 3 : Deselect by pressing `ctrl-D` :)

Comment: that is not a vector mask

Comment: @Luciano How about layer masks :)

Comment: (It's a layer mask)

Comment: @mayersdesign edited already :)

Comment: you can use a vector shape as layer mask, or do the selection as you did - that is a bitmap mask: the first line still says "Vector mask"

Comment: @Luciano sorry actually wasn't noticed it all while editing :) thanks all